# How to index set of subsets in ZIMPL?

Tags: syntax-error, scip

Given S as a set of subsets, I'd like to print it out, and index it:

```
set S[]:=subsets({1..5}, 3); 
do forall <i> in S do print S[i];

# Neither does the following work:

do print S;
```

I get the following error:

```
Reading debug.zpl
*** Error 142: Unknown index <> for symbol "S"
*** File: debug.zpl Line 2
*** do forall <i> in S do print S[i];
***                     ^^^
```

How can I index set of subsets?

Answer (score 1):

```
do forall <i> in indexset(S) do print S[i];
```

should do.